Prove that if $A=\{X\subseteq \mathbb{N}\mid |X| < \infty \}$, then $|A|=\aleph_{0}$.
I am currently reading book of proof. It's an exercise from page 280. The author uses the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to proof it. But I couldn't understand the proof he presented.
From my perspective, I thought that $A$ may be the power set of $\mathbb{N}$. For the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ is $|\mathbb{N}|$. So the items in $A$ could be listed according to the size of the subset, so $A$ is infinite countably, then $|A|=\aleph_{0}$. I don't know whether my thought is correct. So I look into the proof of the author.
The author use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to proof this, but I couldn't understand his proof. I don't know why using fundamental theorem of arithmetic either.
His proof as follows:

For each natural number $n$, let $p_{n}$ be the $n$-th prime number.

This is the first point where I started to feel confused. He connects the natural number $n$ with the $n$-th prime number.

Now consider any element $X\in{A}$. If $X\ne\emptyset$, then $X=\{n_{1},n_{2},\dots,n_{k}\}$, where $k=|X|$ and $n_{i}\in\mathbb{N}$ for each $i\le{i}\le{k}$.

There he defines the item $X$ in set $A$.

Define a function $f$: $A\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ as follows: $f(\{n_{1},n_{2},n_{3},\dots,n_{k}\})=p_{n_{1}}p_{n_{2}}\dots p_{n_{k}}$, and $f(\emptyset)=0$

There he define a bijection function from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. Every set in $A$ could be map to some multiple of prime numbers. For this problem, I think we aim to build a bijection from $A$ to $N$. But he includes a $\{0\}$. Why using $p_{n_{1}}p_{n_{2}}\dots p_{n_{k}}$ as the bijection? This is what confuses me most.
And then, he prove that $f$ is a bijection.

Let $X=\{n_{1},n_{2},n_{3},\dots,n_{k}\}$ and $Y=\{m_{1},m_{2},m_{3},\dots,m_{k}\}$ and $X\ne Y$. Then there is an integer $a$ that belongs to one of $X$ or $Y$ but not the other. Then the prime factorization of one of the numbers $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ uses the prime number $p_{a}$ but the prime factorization of the other does not use $p_{a}$. It follows that $f(X)\ne f(Y)$ by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Thus $f$ is injective.
So each $X\in A$ is associated with an integer $f(X)\ge{0}$, and no 2 different sets are associated with the same number. So we can list the elements in $X$ in increasing order of the numbers $f(X)$. So $A$ is countably infinite.

The bold part is where I am totally confused. Besides, how does he know that the function is surjective? Is every number in $\mathbb{N}$ is associated with a set in $A$?
Can you help me explain this proof? Thank you very much!
P.S. There's another exercise that follows this exercise. He asks me to use a bijective function $\phi(m,n)=2^{n-1}(2m-1)$ and fundamental theorem of arithmetic to prove that the Catesian product of 2 infinite countably sets is an infinite countably set.

Let us organize this answer into the several questions you asked throughout your post.

From my perspective, I thought that $A$ may be the power set of $\mathbb{N}$.

Since $A$ are the finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, then $A\subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ (where $\subset$ denotes the strict inclusion). For example, the subset of even numbers belongs to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, but not to $A$. Also, it is well knwon that $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|=2^{\aleph_0}>|\mathbb{N}|$.

This is the first point where I started to feel confused.

This is the everyday life in every mathematician.

But he includes a $\{0\}$.

This part really intrigues me. We know that $\varnothing$ belongs to $A$, since the empty set is finite. Hence, the function $f$ to be well-defined has to map $\varnothing$ to some number. However, I would have chosen $f(\varnothing)=1$ since is the identity of the multiplication. But I would say choosing $0$ or $1$ is not the most important part of the proof.

The bold part is where I am totally confused.

Sice $X\neq Y$, then $X\nsubseteq Y$ or $Y\nsubseteq X$ which, in other words, means that there is an element of $X$ ($Y$ respectively) that does not belong to $Y$ ($X$ resp) —The most confusing part for me is using the notation $a$ to refer an element of the type $n_i$ or $m_j$, where the letter $a$ does not appear anywhere else, but this is another story. Hence, suppose that $n_i\in X$ but $n_i\notin Y$. By definition of $f$, the prime $p:=p_{n_i}$ appears in the number $f(X)\in\mathbb{N}$, but not in $f(Y)\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence, $p|f(X)$, but $p\nmid f(Y)$. If $f(X)=f(Y)$, the same prime would divide $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$, but this is not the case, so $f(X)\neq f(Y)$. Since this is true for all $X\neq Y$, then injectivity is proven.

Besides, how does he know that the function is surjective? Is every number in $\mathbb{N}$ is associated with a set in $A$?

In fact, it is not: $4\notin\operatorname{Im}(f)$, since $4=2^2$ and every number in $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ must be factorized in primes with exponent one. However, since $f$ is injective, $|A|=|\operatorname{Im}(f)|$. And we know that $\operatorname{Im}(f)\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, so $|\operatorname{Im}(f)|\leq|\mathbb{N}|$, and $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is infinite, since every prime belongs to the image of $f$. Thus, $|\operatorname{Im}(f)|=|\mathbb{N}|$. So we can conclude that $|A|=|\mathbb{N}|$.
I hope this answer helps you in understanding the proof.

I have one more little question. If an infinite set is countable(in other words, it has an injection from $A$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}$), then we can say that it's an infinite countably set? So there's no need to find the precise bijective function? I previously thought that we must find a bijective function to prove that a set is infinite countably.

Indeed, being infinite countable means that the set must be in a bijective correspondence with the natural numbers. Nevertheless, $A$ is infinite by definition (since${n}\in A$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$). Hence, the only thing we need to prove is that $A$ is countable, which is equivalent to find an injective map $A\to\mathbb{N}$ (notice also that being infinite is finding a surjective map $A\to\mathbb{N}$, that is why the bijection). Proving that $f$ is injective is essentially proving that $A$ is countable. Since it is also infinite, we are done.
